Decrypt .Net cookie using Typescript or Nodejs
Im trying to decrypt a .Net cookie using Typescript but the retrieved cookie is serialised binary data and there are many bytes that cannot be read. Im trying to figure out which format it is in and since it came from .Net memory there is no way to figure out and make the information more readable.
Here is where we started to build our own custom util from:
exampleFromGithub
var unprotectedCookie = unprotectAspNetIdentityCookie(cookiecontent, ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Identity.Application", "v2"], getMasterKey);
Basically here is an implementation of the function described above:
export function unprotectAspNetIdentityCookie(identityCookie: string, purposeStrings: string[],  
     getMasterKeyById: (keyId: string) => Promise<Buffer>) {
  
let protectedPayload: Buffer;
  let cursor = 0;

  try {
    protectedPayload = dotNetBase64UrlDecode(identityCookie);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Could not decode identity cookie:${e}`);
    return null;
  }

  if (!verifyMagicHeader(protectedPayload)) {
    console.log('Identity cookie protected payload did not start with expected magic header');
    return null;
  }
  cursor += 4;

  const keyIdBuffer =  Buffer.from((protectedPayload as Uint8Array).slice(cursor, cursor + SIZE_KEY_ID));
  cursor += SIZE_KEY_ID;
  let formatedKeyId: string;
  try {
    formatedKeyId = formatKeyId(keyIdBuffer);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Could not read key id from identity cookie');
    return null;
  }

  return getMasterKeyById(formatedKeyId)
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(`Could not find master key for key id ${formatedKeyId}`);
      return null;
    })
    .then((masterKeyBuffer: Buffer | null) => {
      if(!masterKeyBuffer) return;

      const aadBuffer = generateAad(keyIdBuffer, purposeStrings);

      const contextHeaderBuffer = getContextHeader();

      // below we will read the different sections of the cipher text. This is assumed to
      // have the following format:
      // { keyModifier | IV | encryptedData | MAC(IV | encryptedPayload) }
      const modifierBuffer = protectedPayload.slice(cursor, cursor + SIZE_KEY_MODIFIER);
      cursor += SIZE_KEY_MODIFIER;
      // the initialization vector is used to initialize the symmetric encryption algorithm, so
      // the size of iv will be equal to the block size of the algorithm
      const ivBuffer = protectedPayload.slice(cursor, cursor + SIZE_SYMMETRIC_ALGORITHM_BLOCK);
      cursor += SIZE_KEY_MODIFIER;

      // the remainder of the cipher text is encrypted data + MAC tag.
      // we are only interested in the encrypted data, so we strip the HMAC digest.
      const encryptedDataBuffer = protectedPayload.slice(
        cursor,
        protectedPayload.length - SIZE_VALIDATION_HMAC_DIGEST
      );

      const contextBuffer = Buffer.concat([contextHeaderBuffer, modifierBuffer]);
      const derivedKeyBuffer = deriveKeysSP800_108_CTR_HMAC512(
        masterKeyBuffer,
        aadBuffer,
        contextBuffer
      );

      const encryptionKeyBuffer = derivedKeyBuffer.slice(0, SIZE_SYMMETRIC_ALGORITHM_KEY);

      console.log(`ciphertext: ${encryptedDataBuffer.length} ${encryptedDataBuffer.toString("hex")}`);


      const decipher =  crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', encryptionKeyBuffer, ivBuffer);
      console.log(`decipher: ${decipher}`);
      const outputStart = decipher.update(encryptedDataBuffer);
      const outputEnd = decipher.final();
      const decipheredPayload = Buffer.concat([outputStart, outputEnd]);

      return Buffer.concat([outputStart, outputEnd]);
    });
}

I am able to retrieve the cipher text, however when im trying to decipher the same using the last function crypto.decipher('aes-256-cbc', encryptionKeyBuffer, ivBuffer), it throws the following error
decipher: [object Object]
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
node:internal/crypto/cipher:193
  const ret = this[kHandle].final();
                            ^

Error: error:1C80006B:Provider routines::wrong final block length
    at Decipheriv.final (node:internal/crypto/cipher:193:29)
    at C:\Projects\IN\decrypt_aspnet_auth\dist\decrypt.js:119:36
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  library: 'Provider routines',
  reason: 'wrong final block length',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH'
}

